# Are there security implications to referencing webpages sequentially?

Tags: security, url, web-development

For instance, what is the reasoning behind YouTube URL assignment using the format:

?v=qv-8pquw9wQ

?v=lW5kB906mh8

?v=SwUg7oTZoTY

Instead of:

?v=0Cn0phjvk8a

?v=0Cn0phjvk8b

?v=0Cn0phjvk8c

Comment: There isn't this question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumeration of the URLs would be trivial in the sequential assignment and leak the order and existence of prior videos such as ones that aren't publicly visible.